# R shiny Rmd: How to use Rmd to download multiple plots and tables into html or word file?

Tags: r, download, shiny

I am trying to download multiple plots and tables into one html file. Here is my situation:

```
datatable <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
})
```

I use the above code to read a csv file to datatable, then I use the following code to do some pre-processing for the dataset that will be analyzed:

```
pickedsinglefactor <- function(singlefactor,datatable){
  ...
  e <- ddply()
}
```

In shinyServer, I use the following code to receive the data:

```
singlefactordataframe <- reactive(pickedsinglefactor(input$sfactor,datatable))
```

The following are my plots and tables:

```
output$singleplotcount <- renderPlotly({
    e <- singlefactordataframe()
    ...
    pcount <- ggplotly(pcount)
    pcount
  })
```

.......................

```
  output$singletable <- renderDataTable({
    e <- singlefactordataframe()
    if (input$checksinglefactorvalues) {e <- subset(e,e[,1] %in% input$sfactorvalues)}
    e
  })
```

In fact, I might have a lot of plots and tables that need to be download into a html file, the number of which cannot be pre-defined. So, how can I download all the plots and tables into one file?
Any help would be appreciated.